# Position images exactly using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create dozens of small images and position them absolutely on the screen relative to the top and left of the screen. I have a page with one div on it and, at the moment, I am experimenting with creating each element using javascript. How can I position each element precisely?

```
var divo = document.getElementById('pagediv');
var objImage = document.createElement('img');
objImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/Red_L.gif');
divo.appendChild(objImage);
```

That is creating the image okay and putting it on the screen. But how can you tell it exactly where to be positioned?

Comment: what do you mean positioned? At specific x/y coordinates or after a certain element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the images dynamically,I believe you could could run it through a loop and position the images.

```
    var divo = document.getElementById('pagediv');
    var leftPos = 0;
    var newSrc = '';
    for(i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++)
    {
        newSrc = "images/red_"+i+".png";
        var objImage = document.createElement('img');
        objImage.src = newSrc;
        objImage.style.left=leftPos+20+"px";
        objImage.style.zIndex=2;
        objImage.style.position="absolute";
        leftPos = objImage.style.width;
        divo.appendChild(objImage);
    }
```

If your images are named `red_1.png,red_2.png` and so on,this code will position the images one next to another with a spacing of 20px in between each other.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should take a look at [CSS absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html).

Answer (score 0):

"At specific x/y coordinates"

Set the CSS for it.

```
var divo = document.getElementById('pagediv');
var objImage = document.createElement('img');
objImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/Red_L.gif');
objImage.style.top="100px";
objImage.style.left="100px";
objImage.style.zIndex=2;
objImage.style.position="absolute";
divo.appendChild(objImage);
```

Comment: If you set the position like this,won't the dozen images get placed on top of each other?

Comment: @harsha I sure hope the OP is smart enough to set the top/left for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Using `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` could potentially solve your problem http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html — but it can be buggy in some browsers. I would suggest employing `getBoundingClientRect` http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/ to get and offset each images x/y coordinate.